# NullPointerException in java JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception

I am trying to parse JSON from web api for the first time and what I get is NullPointerException. What I did is downloaded json .jar file and add it like external library, then added JSON into StringBuffer and just to see if it works - added System.Out.println. 
Then I made JSON Object but did not sure for the argument, should it be stringBuffer object?
In the end, I tried to make an JSON Array and search the string "Država" from it, but then I get this NullPointerException. 
Where am I wrong?

edit: I dont use Maven yet.

my code:

```
try {   

    double responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("Broj tečajnice = "+ responseCode);

    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputLine);

    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Država");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        String drzava = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("Država");
        System.out.println(drzava);
    }
    in.close();
    }
    catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And JSON from web:

```
[{"Broj tečajnice":"188",
"Datum primjene":"30.09.2018",
"Država":"Australija",
"Šifra valute":"036",
"Valuta":"AUD",
"Jedinica":1,
"Kupovni za devize":"4,605078",
"Srednji za devize":"4,618935",
"Prodajni za devize":"4,632792"},

{"Broj tečajnice":"188",
"Datum primjene":"30.09.2018",
"Država":"Kanada",
"Šifra valute":"124",
"Valuta":"CAD",
"Jedinica":1,
"Kupovni za devize":"4,903440",
"Srednji za devize":"4,918195",
"Prodajni za devize":"4,932950"}
...etc...]
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
at org.json.JSONTokener.<init>(JSONTokener.java:66)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:420)
at pretvaracValuta.PretvaracController.connection(PretvaracController.java:49)
at pretvaracValuta.PretvaracController.initialize(PretvaracController.java:24)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at pretvaracValuta.Main.start(Main.java:14)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$106(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$119(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$117(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$118(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$450(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please also include the full stack trace for the Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: Please share crash logs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First problem**

You're passing the wrong value into the `JSONObject` constructor. Look at this piece of code:

```
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(inputLine);
```

The `while` loop is only going to complete when `inputLine` is null - so your final line is equivalent to:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(null);
```

... which obviously isn't what you want. I think you want:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
```

Note that you probably want to use `StringBuilder` rather than `StringBuffer` as well, to avoid pointless synchronization.

**Next problem**

If your JSON is actually of the form `[ ... ]` then it's an array, not an object at the top level. So you probably want:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response.toString());
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String drzava = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("Država");
    System.out.println(drzava);
}
```

After all, if you look at your JSON, it doesn't have `Država` as the name of a property with an array as the value.

Comment: I tried that also but then I get this exception:  org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Comment: @ZoranBajcer: Then that's an entirely different problem. So what's the value of `response.ToString()` when the loop has finished? What did you expect it to be? If it starts with `[` then you probably want to call `new JSONArray` instead. I'll put that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong input for your JSonObject:

```
double responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
try (InputStreamReader  sr =new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(sr)){  
// ^ this is Jdk7+, will close your streams after the block exists, like in finally block 

...

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString()); // pass the input as a String

....
}catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your `response` variable holds the input in a form of a String, whereas `inputLine` holds only single line. And after the last iteration, it's set to null. Which will cause an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get JSONArray and then iterate it for parse the required value.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(inputLine);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(array.get(i).get("Država"));
}
```